# How do I use Spring Cloud Kubernetes to programmatically write a ConfigMap value?

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have a service that uses Spring Cloud Kubernetes Config to reload its configuration when a value in a ConfigMap changes.  That all works great.

Is it possible to use Spring Cloud Kubernetes (or one of its dependencies) to **write** a ConfigMap value?  I didn't see any examples of this in the documentation ([here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/)).  Can I do this programmatically, or do I need to call the underlying Kubernetes APIs to do this?

Comment: nope, no such thing is possible at the moment. You could go to our github page, explain your use case and may be we will create such a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Eugene's reply:

No, this is impossible at the moment to do so. You can go to [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes#1-why-do-you-need-spring-cloud-kubernetes) and create an issue with the explanation of your use case, and this feature **can be created** within the future releases.